# Solr and big synonym file

Tags: solr, synonym

I have a big synonym dictionary and I created a file correctly formated to use it with solr.
This file has a size of 4mb. But when I want to start solr using Tomcat,  solr is blocked in start.

What is the problem ? The file is too big ?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the error message/stacktrace ? Can u start it without the file?

Comment: I can start without the file and I can start if I remove some text of this file. There is no error, the console block at "INFO: unique key field :id". I feel that Solr want to start but it can't. I already increased the memory size of tomcat (Xmx1024m) but it change nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

we created a new synonymsfilter to address this problem, the old synonymsfilter was quite bad with such large synonyms files:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-3233

Unless something changes, should make it into 3.4

Answer (score 0):

I think it has nothing to do with tomcat memory, try increasing solr memory.
Found [this](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/size-of-synonyms-txt-td3095712.html) link which mentions that synonym.txt will take lot of heap space, so mostly its due to solr running out of memory

Comment: How can I increase solr memory ? In solrconifg.xml ?

Comment: While starting solr add an option -Xmx4096 , keep checking the increase in memory to confirm whether its running out of memory while startup

Comment: I start Solr through Tomcat... So it's why i increase memory size of Tomcat

Comment: solr,tomcat will run as separate processes, check how much memory each one is getting, never ran solr through tomcat, hope this helps